# EF creates a new UserProfile every time I reference one?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

My issue is the fact that the following code creates not only a ProtectedPassword (as it should) but also creates the owner being inserted into it even though that owner alread exists.

```
UserProfile user = PublicUtility.GetAccount(User.Identity.Name); //gets an existing UserProfile
ProtectedPassword pw = new ProtectedPassword(model.Name, user, model.Password);
ProtectedPassword.Create(pw);
```

Thus after creating a new ProtectedPassword I end up with a new UserProfile (with the same values as the previous one except a new ID) being referenced.

I've been messing with this issue for a couple of hours now and would appreciate if someone could help me!

Btw, I use ASP.NET MVC4 and EF Code First.

Firstly, the entities:
ProtectedPassword:

```
    [Table("ProtectedPassword")]
    public class ProtectedPassword : ProtectedProperty
    {

        [Required]
        [MinLength(3)]
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        private ProtectedPassword()
        {
        }

        public ProtectedPassword(string name, UserProfile owner, string password)
        {
            Name = name;
            Owner = owner;
            Password = password;
            SubId = PublicUtility.GenerateRandomString(8, 0);
            Type = ProtectedPropertyType.Password;
        }

        public static bool Create(ProtectedPassword pw)
        {
            try
            {
                using (MediaProfitsDb db = new MediaProfitsDb())
                {
                    db.ProtectedPasswords.Add(pw);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
}
```

Inherits from ProtectedProperty:

```
public class ProtectedProperty
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int PropertyId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string SubId { get; set; }

        public int Downloads { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public UserProfile Owner { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public ProtectedPropertyType Type { get; set; }

    }
```

And finally UserProfile:

```
    [Table("UserProfile")]
    public class UserProfile
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string AffiliateId { get; set; }
        public UserProfile Referer { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Balance { get; private set; }
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string PaypalEmail { get; set; }
        public int AllTimeEarnings { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the UserProfile object on the Password is not attached the the DbContext that you're using to Insert. This makes EF think that it's a new object.

Try:

```
using (MediaProfitsDb db = new MediaProfitsDb())
{
    db.UserProfiles.Attach(pw.UserProfile);
    db.ProtectedPasswords.Add(pw);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return true;
}
```